# multi-threading not working in aomedia av1 build with visual studio

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio, cmake, pthreads, mingw

I managed to build AV1 codec https://aomedia.googlesource.com/aom/ with visual studio thanks to the command

```
cmake path/to/aom -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
```

however the encoder only use one thread even with the option --threads, in the code it seems to use pthread. Do I need to do a different build with pthread emulation or do I miss a flag to enable multi-threading on windows 10 64bit for this codec?

Answer (score 1):

i make AOM AV1 encoder to work in parallel by adding tiles `--tile-columns=1 --tile-rows=0` , where `--tile-columns` and `--tile-rows` denote  log2 of tile columns and rows.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in x264, option `--threads` only limits thread usage. To enable threading, set `--row-mt=1`, and optionally use tiling, which has great threading performance but reduces efficiency quite a bit at lower resolutions.

Loop restoration hurts threading, so for better threading you should disable it, especially when using many tiles: `--enable-restoration=0`

Answer (score -1):

hmm, well av1 is missing multi-threading, should arrive when they get around finishing specs lol